# Button forward with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, domcontentloaded

I have a button in HTML and I want to forward to another page when clicked

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);

  function init() {
    let url = document.getElementsByClassName("Button__LandingPage");
    url.addEventListener("click", forwardURL, false);

    function forwardURL() {
      location.replace("https://www.w3schools.com");
    }
  };
})();
```

```html
<button class="Button Button__LandingPage" name="landingPageButton">Home</button>
```

What do I wrong here? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is the parenthesis at the beginning actually in your code?

Comment: Just an idea: why don't you use [an anchor element `<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)? It's more fitting, it's more accessible, and it requires zero javascript. You can style it to look like a button with CSS.

Comment: thank you guys.. its a school task and my professor gave us a code snippet we needed to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a collection not a single result. It would be better to use an id with `getElementById` instead. But, in your case, you can get the first element of the collection with `getElementsByClassName[0]`. Here's a full example:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);

  function init() {
    let url = document.getElementsByClassName("Button__LandingPage")[0];
    url.addEventListener("click", forwardURL, false);

    function forwardURL() {
      //location.replace("https://www.w3schools.com");
      console.log("Forward");
    }
  };
})();
```

```html
<button class="Button Button__LandingPage" name="landingPageButton">Home</button>
```

Comment: omg.. thank you so much! I totally forget to put [0] at the end. Thanks! :)